# How do I group a Elastic Stack alert by Docker Instances?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elastic-stack

A certain periodic task is supposed to happen once a minute. I can send an  alert when this is hanging with the following condition in a Threshold Alert.

```
WHEN count() GROUPED OVER top 1 'periodicTaskLog' IS BELOW 1 FOR THE LAST 2 minutes
```

(That uses the basic Watch creation GUI. I can use the Advanced Watch JSON if needed.)

My complication: This task is occurring separately in 2 or more Docker Instances, and I want to check that *none of them* is blocked. (This is in Google AppEngine Flexible Environment.)

I want to say "The  key `periodicTaskLog` must occur each minute in each instance. Otherwise send an alert."

I have the field `instance_name`. Each instance's name is  an arbitrary value,like  `"a58hgh12g2"` or `"h9mm48dfh"`,  different on each deployment. So, I cannot  code the condition to include these names as literals.

So, how do I group in this way?

Comment: First, you want to know how to write this query in Elastic?(I don't get how Kibana has to do with your question). Second, is the field `instance_name` is a filed which only this Docker instances which you would like to check have?

Comment: " in Elastic". OK, I made the correction.

Comment: I can do a search that gathers  only  this set of 2-3 instances. So, distinguishing these instances from others is not a problem. But ... the query has to aggregate within a given   instance to tell me whether the event has occured in the last minute in each instance,  separately.

Comment: You don't want to hardcode instance names, rigth? But how should the query know what instances you have?

Comment: In most query languages this can be done with a subquery
where you select unique instanceName  for log lines in the last minute

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See answer  [here](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/how-do-i-aggregate-across-subsearches/130825/4)

```
{
  "trigger": {
    "schedule": {
      "interval": "10s"
    }
  },
  "input": {
    "search": {
      "request": {
        "search_type": "query_then_fetch",
        "indices": [
          "packetbeat-*"
        ],
        "types": [],
        "body": {
          "size": 0,
          "query": {
            "match_all": {}
          },
          "aggs": {
            "unique_beat_names": {
              "terms": {
                "field": "ip",
                "size": 5
              },
              "aggs": {
                "response_code": {
                  "filter": {
                    "exists": {
                      "field": "dns.response_code"
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "condition": {
    "script": {
      "source": "ctx.vars.missing=false;for (def beat_name : ctx.payload.aggregations.unique_beat_names.buckets){if(beat_name.doc_count == 0 || beat_name.response_code.doc_count == 0){ctx.vars.missing=true;}}return ctx.vars.missing;",
      "lang": "painless"
    }
  },
  "actions": {
    "my-logging-action": {
      "logging": {
        "level": "info",
        "text": "Oh yea"
      }
    }
  }
}
```